# Translating async method into Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to wrap my head around Combine.

Here's a method I want to translate into Combine, so that it would return AnyPublisher.

```swift
func getToken(completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
    dispatchQueue.async {
        do {
            if let localEncryptedToken = try self.readTokenFromKeychain() {
                let decryptedToken = try self.tokenCryptoHelper.decrypt(encryptedToken: localEncryptedToken)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(decryptedToken))
                }
            } else {
                self.fetchToken(completion: completion)
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The whole thing executes on a separate dispatch queue because reading from Keychain and decryption can be slow.

My first attempt to embrace Combine

```swift
func getToken() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
    do {
        if let localEncryptedToken = try readTokenFromKeychain() {
            let decryptedToken = try tokenCryptoHelper.decrypt(encryptedToken: localEncryptedToken)
            return Result.success(decryptedToken).publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        } else {
            return fetchToken() // also rewritten to return AnyPublisher<String, Error>
        }
    } catch {
        return Result.failure(error).publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

But how would I move reading from Keychain and decryption onto separate queue? It probably should look something like

```
func getToken() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
    return Future<String, Error> { promise in
        self.dispatchQueue.async {
            do {
                if let localEncryptedToken = try self.readTokenFromKeychain() {
                    let decryptedToken = try self.tokenCryptoHelper.decrypt(encryptedToken: localEncryptedToken)
                    promise(.success(decryptedToken))
                } else {
                    // should I fetchToken().sink here?
                }
            } catch {
                promise(.failure(error))
            }
        }    
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

How would I return a publisher from my private method call? (see comment in code)

Are there any prettier solutions?

Comment: @Rob oh sorry, that's a mistake, corrected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you’ve refactored `readTokenFromKeyChain`, `decrypt`, and `fetchToken` to return `AnyPublisher<String, Error>` themselves, you can then do:

```
func getToken() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
    readTokenFromKeyChain()
        .flatMap { self.tokenCryptoHelper.decrypt(encryptedToken: $0) }
        .catch { _ in self.fetchToken() }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

That will read the keychain, if it succeeded, decrypt it, and if it didn’t succeed, it will call `fetchToken`. And having done all of that, it will make sure the final result is delivered on the main queue.

---

I think that’s the right general pattern. Now, let's talk about that `dispatchQueue`: Frankly, I’m not sure I’m seeing anything here that warrants running on a background thread, but let’s imagine you wanted to kick this off in a background queue, then, you `readTokenFromKeyChain` might dispatch that to a background queue:

```
func readTokenFromKeyChain() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
    dispatchQueue.publisher { promise in
        let query: [CFString: Any] = [
            kSecReturnData: true,
            kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrAccount: "token",
            kSecAttrService: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!]

        var extractedData: AnyObject?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &extractedData)

        if
            status == errSecSuccess,
            let retrievedData = extractedData as? Data,
            let string = String(data: retrievedData, encoding: .utf8)
        {
            promise(.success(string))
        } else {
            promise(.failure(TokenError.failure))
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, that’s using a simple little method, `publisher` that I added to `DispatchQueue`:

```
extension DispatchQueue {
    /// Dispatch block asynchronously
    /// - Parameter block: Block

    func publisher<Output, Failure: Error>(_ block: @escaping (Future<Output, Failure>.Promise) -> Void) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
        Future<Output, Failure> { promise in
            self.async { block(promise) }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

For the sake of completeness, this is a sample `fetchToken` implementation:

```
func fetchToken() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
    let request = ...

    return URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .map { $0.data }
        .decode(type: ResponseObject.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .map { $0.payload.token }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: glad it looks kind of similar to what I came up with:) As for running on a background thread, is that ok if I .subscribe(on: dispatchQueue) in my whole pipeline (as in my answer), instead of wrapping some parts of the pipeline in dispatch blocks? Also, I think, running something on a background thread seems like an implementation detail, so should be declared inside of the method, whereas receiving something on a particular queue is probably a responsibility of a client, so `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` should be done by the client. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think I could find a solution

```swift
private func readTokenFromKeychain() -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error> {
    ...
}

func getToken() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
    return readTokenFromKeychain()
        .flatMap { localEncryptedToken -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> in
            if let localEncryptedToken = localEncryptedToken {
                return Result.success(localEncryptedToken).publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
            } else {
                return self.fetchToken()
            }
        }
        .flatMap {
            return self.tokenCryptoHelper.decrypt(encryptedToken: $0)
        }
        .subscribe(on: dispatchQueue)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

But I had to make functions I call within `getToken()` return publishers too to Combine them well.
There probably should be error handling somewhere but this is the next thing for me to learn.